# Custom STL compatible iterator for iterating over columns of a 2D array class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define a custom STL compatible iterator for iterating over the columns of a 2D array class.  The final piece that I'm stuck on is defining the iterator difference operator:

```cpp
difference_type operator-(const self_type& rhs) const noexcept
```

For example:
Data is stored in row major order as such (values represent the iterator difference from begin() to end() row major):

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
```

And I would like to access it like (values represent the iterator difference from begin() to end() now column major):

```
0  3  6
1  4  7
2  5  8
```

What I have so far only works for ~half of the elements, so obviously not correct:

```cpp
difference_type operator-(const self_type& rhs) const noexcept
{
    const auto idx = ptr_ - rhs.ptr_;
    const auto row = idx / numCols_;
    const auto col = idx % numCols_;
    return row + col * numRows_;
}
```

For elements 0 and 7 of the row based I get:

```
idx = 6 - 4 = 7    
row = 2 / 3 = 2  
col = 2 % 3 = 1
diff = 2 + 1 * 3 = 5
```

which is correct.
For elements 6 and 4 of the row based I get:

```
idx = 6 - 4 = 2  
row = 2 / 3 = 0  
col = 2 % 3 = 2
diff = 0 + 2 * 3 = 6
```

When the correct answer should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to remap `ptr_` and `rhs.ptr_` to their sequence numbers (in the order you want to go through) and subtract the values:

```
difference_type operator-(const self_type& rhs) const noexcept
{
    const auto row1 = ptr_ / numCols_;
    const auto col1 = ptr_ % numCols_;
    const auto seq1 = col1 * numCols_ + row1;
    const auto row2 = rhs.ptr_ / numCols_;
    const auto col2 = rhs.ptr_ % numCols_;
    const auto seq2 = col2 * numCols_ + row2;
    return seq2 - seq1;
}
```